# Not displaying decimals with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, decimal, rounding

I want to display the value of a slider into a label. The label is called rate and the slider is sliderrate, I tried this:

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    rate.text = String(round(sliderrate.value))
}
```

As you can see I tried to round it in order to not display the decimals, but it's not working, I still have one decimal. Can someone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift's rounding functions return the same type as you put into them. So if you round a `Double`, what you get back is still a `Double`. To display the rounded number as an integer, convert it to an `Int` first:

```
Int(slidernote.value.rounded())
```

Alternately, you can use the `lround` function from the standard C library, which returns an Int:

```
import Foundation

lround(slidernote.value)
```